# Why is $EQ_{cfg}$ not recognizable but is co-turing-recognizable

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, computation-models

I've seen the proof that $EQ_{CFG}$ is not recognizable but its complement is, my problem is that in the proof that it's complement is recognizable, it says that we test every string in $\sum^*$ and checks if it's generated by one of the $CFG$s but not the other. My question is that why don't we use this method to solve $EQ_{CFG}$ problem, where we iterate on all possible strings in $\sum^*$ and confirm that it either gets generated or not by both $CFGs$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here comes from the requirement to *halt*.

An algorithm that returns "true", must always do so in finite time, hence, it will never be able to go through all strings in $\Sigma^*$ and confirm that it is either generated not by both CFGs.

However, for the complement problem, the requirement changes drastically: It is enough to show **one** string $w$ such that $w\in L(G_1)$ and $w\notin L(G_2)$ (or vice versa) to know that $L(G_1)\neq L(G_2)$. This allows us to find this string $w$ and halt when we see it, without the need to continue and check more strings.

I hope this gave you some intuition :) (P.S, this is **not** a formal proof)